# Dog rolls in poop at daycare

Tags: dogs, behavior, defecation

We have a 1 year old BernieDoodle that is pretty well behaved at the house. We take him to Doggy Daycare once or twice a week so he can get some energy out and mingle since we work.

At daycare he has lately been rolling in his (or others, not sure) poop. It's about every other time. Someone mentioned he might be trying to eat it so try changing food. The odd thing is this only happens there. When we leave him at the house alone he is fine. He is a very social and happy dog at home and there so not sure what this means.

Any thoughts? Are we taking him too much maybe? Food?

Comment: Have you asked the daycare workers to observe him? They should be able to tell you more about when it happens. Is he happy, upset, playing or on his own. Dogs do sometimes just like rolling in something smelly...

Comment: Thanks for posting! My Bernedoodle, now almost 8 months, suddenly stared rolling in poop at daycare - not long after he was neutered. Don't now if that's connected, but feel relieved another Bernedoodle does this.

Comment: Why is the doggy day care leaving the poop there? If they remove it immediately, he wouldn't be able to roll in it....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Scent-rolling](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20170608-the-many-reasons-why-dogs-might-roll-in-smelly-poo) is 100% a normal behavior in dogs.

From the [Clinical Behavioral Medicine for Small Animals](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1568692.Clinical_Behavioral_Medicine_for_Small_Animals):

> By rolling, dogs simultaneously disrupt the mark of another animal, deposit their own scent, and acquire some of the other animal's scent. They also groom by shedding some of their undercoat when they roll. The extent to which the latter might be important in a masking situation useful in predation has not been fully explored. Dogs seem to find it pleasurable to roll in some scents that humans consider fairly offensive, which may mean that they are responding neurochemically to some pheromonal cue.
>
> Once the dog has located the area that stimulates it to roll and has begun to drop, it is almost impossible to stop even the most obedient dog. If clients absolutely need to avoid this behavior, they will have to be vigilant, use a leash, and learn to read canine communication.

Doggy daycare is a wonderful place to socialize and have fun, his diet does not have an impact on these behaviors - your dog is simply being a dog.